# What would be command(s) to expand the file system on raspbian?

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi

I have a number of raspberry PIs attached to various networks distributed over a large area so this will have to be a remote process. I need to expand the file system so it fills the full 8Gb (currently 2Gb). We use Puppet to distribute updates but I am not sure what the process of commands is.

I know this can be achieved locally using raspi-config but I will need to create a script or send a command to do this over the network.

Answer (score 1):

raspi-config is a shell script. The section on memory expansion is listed below. Here are the basic steps:

1. Verify that the desired expansion is on a SD card, not external device, and not more than the two normal partitions.
2. Determine the exact partition and desired partition size. (parted)
3. Change the size of the partition in the partition table. (This usually requires a reboot to take effect.) (fdisk)
4. Expand the filesystem to the complete size of the partition (which was resized in step 3 above). This is setup as a shell script to run after reboot. (resize2fs)

Because there are minor differences in the size of SD cards, even different models from the same manufacturer, it would be extremely difficult to give a more specific set of commands.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Part of raspi-config http://github.com/asb/raspi-config
# ...

if ! [ -h /dev/root]; then
  whiptail --msgbox '/dev/root does not exist or is not a symlink. Don't know how to expand" 20 60 2
  return 0
fi

ROOT_PART=$(readlink /dev/root)
PART_NUM=${ROOT_PART#mmcblk0p}
if [ "$PART_NUM" = "$ROOT_PART" ]; then
  whiptail --msgbox "/dev/root is not an SD card. Don't know how to expand" 20 60 2
  return 0
fi

# NOTE: the NOOBS partition layout confuses parted. For now, let's only
# agree to work with a sufficiently simple partition layout
if [ "$PART_NUM" -ne 2 ]; then
  whiptail msgbox "Your partition layout is not currently supported by this tool. You rae probably using NOOBS, in which case your root filesystem is already expanded anyway." 20 60 2
  return 0
fi

LAST_PART_NUM=$(parted /dev/mmcblk0 -ms unit s p | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d:)

if [ "$LAST_PART_NUM" != "$PART_NUM" ]; then
  whiptail --msgbox "/dev/root is not the last partition. Don't know how to expand" 20 60 2
  return 0
fi

# Get the starting offset of the root partition
PART_START=$(parted /dev/mmcblk0 -ms unit s p | grep "^${PART_NUM}" | cut -f 2 -d:)
[ "$PART_START" ] || return 1
# Return value will likely be error for fdisk as it fails to reload the
# partition table because the root fs is mounted
fdisk /dev/mmdblk0 <<EOF
p
d
$PART_NUM
n
p
$PART_NUM
$PART_START

p
w
EOF
ASK_TO_REBOOT=1

# now set up an init.d script
cat <<\EOF > /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once &&
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          resize2fs_once
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5 S
# Default-Stop: 
# Short-Description: Resize the root filesystem to fill partition
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting resize2fs_once" &&
    resize2fs /dev/root &&
    rm /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once &&
    update-rc.d resize2fs_once remove &&
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage $0 start" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
EOF

chmod +x /etc/init.d/resize2fs_once &&
update-rc.d resize2fs_once defaults &&
if [ '$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
  whiptail --msgbox "Root partition has been resized.\nThe filesystem will be enlarged upon the next reboot" 20 60 2
fi
```